# Google api translation error

Tags: python, flask, google-translate

Im trying to translate spanish text via googletranslate,

```
@app.route('/out', methods=['POST'])
def translate():
    pl=request.json.get('spanish')
    pl=pl.replace(" ","+")
    payload=pl.encode('utf-8')
    print (payload)
    with urllib.request.urlopen('https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q='+str(payload)+'&target=en&format=text&source=es&key=AIzaSyCS-eBQ5gtBlZU4507OjSFMstHDAp8LIao') as response:
        html = response.read()
```

===============================================================

**But Im getting wrong output**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "spanish": " Se recibió información procedente de dos médicos "
}' http://localhost:5000/out

Output : b 'Information was received from two m? x? 3? x?
```

So I think the text being passed to google translate is `"Se recibió información procedente de dos m? x? 3? x?"`rather than "`Se recibió información procedente de dos médicos` "

How can I ensure that the spanish characters are properly passed to google translate.

Answer (score 0):

Just replacing space with `+` will not work. In this case, you can use `quote_plus` from `urllib` module.

Check documentation about `quote_plus`

- [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) - `urllib.parse.quote_plus(string, safe='', encoding=None, errors=None)`
- [python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) - `urllib.quote_plus(string[, safe])`

Quick example here:

```
import urllib.parse

def test():
    str = " Se recibió información procedente de dos médicos "
    converted = urllib.parse.quote_plus(str)
    # => '+Se+recibi%C3%B3+informaci%C3%B3n+procedente+de+dos+m%C3%A9dicos+'
```

Hope this help :)